# How to extract text ONLY from html file using jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I have used this code :

```
String innerHtml = Jsoup.parse(htmlCode,"ISO-8859-1").select("body").html();
```

But it only removes `<html>` tags

Any `HTML` tags inside the `body` will still appear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to get the combined text of the element and all of its children.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `.text()`:

```
Jsoup.parse(htmlCode,"ISO-8859-1").select("body").text();
```

Instead of `.html()`.